# Assign values depending on two conditions (non-trivial)

Tags: r, database, date, methods, variable-assignment

I have quite simple method which assigns values for my list in following way:
1. It goes to the folder with files
2. Checks for the presence of file with the bank number I set 
3. If it is there, it takes data from it for a particular date, again which I set in this method
Here is the method:

```
balancesheet.list <- getBalanceSheet_list("2016-04-01",1481)
```

So in this particular example it goes to the folder, takes the file with number 1481 and assigns data for date 2016-04-01 from this file to my list.

I need to assign data from all files in this folder for each date I need. Data concerning each particular date and bank number should be recorded in separate sublist or just separate list.
In more details, I need to assign data starting from 2007-04-01 and up to 2017-01-01 by months for each bank number.
I've created two csv files: one with date range I need by months:

```
2007-02-01
2007-03-01
2007-04-01
2007-05-01
2007-06-01
...
2016-11-01
2016-12-01
2017-01-01
```

and second with bank numbers I have in general:

```
1
2
21
52
53
55
...
3525
3527
3528
3529
3533
```

My idea was to import those files in R and put them instead "2016-04-01" and 1481. But this is poor idea as I saw.

Also I decided to try following code, not importing any files:

```
balancesheet.list<- getBalanceSheet_list(seq(as.Date("2007-04-01"), as.Date("2017-01-01"), by="months"),1481)
```

R gives an error:
length of argument "pattern" is >1, only first element will be used

As I understand the problem is that it tries to assign data from multiple months in 1 list. May be it is possible to say it to record data by lists or sublists for each separate date?

How any of two ideas can be modernised? Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
lapply(seq(as.Date("2007-04-01"), as.Date("2017-01-01"),by="months"),getBalanceSheet_list,1481)
```

This should give you data from file 1481 for all the dates. I say 'sholud' because it's hard to be sure, when you do not provide any details about `getBalanceSheet_list` function ;)

No we can make a funtion

```
one_file <- function(file) lapply(seq(as.Date("2007-04-01"), as.Date("2017-01-01"),by="months"),getBalanceSheet_list, file)
```

And execute it for all the files. But first we need a vector with their names, say:

```
files<-c(1, 2, 21, ...)
```

Obviously, you have to change `...` into numers. I can't do that, beacuse (again) you did not provide them :)

Now

```
lapply(files, one_file)
```

sholud give you all the informations you need.

You may also replace all the `lapply`'s with `sapply`'s. This would make results look prettier if only `getBalanceSheet_list` returns some pretty object (like vector or single value).